# All print jobs for all printers say "stopped"

Tags: catalina, printing

I can't print to any printers on my network.

All the jobs have the status "stopped" when I try to print. I've tried restarting all printers. I've tried rebooting my Mac.

[image]

Clicking the pause then start button doesn't help.

Clicking the retry icon doesn't help.

How do I restore the ability to print?

Mac OS 10.15.3.

Comment: More than likely, the IP addresses of the printers have changed.  Can you get the IP addresses of the printers now?

Comment: I can get the IP of the printers. I can even see the ink levels of the printer from my computer. I can scan from the printer. I just can't get it to actually print any printers on any network, even networks at my office.